# python won't write to file if there is a function in the script

Tags: python, function

I want to write to a file from a script that also includes functions. Everything seems to work, except that it writes nothing to the file (it writes "" to the file, so it essentially wipes it) if there is a function present in the script; even if it writes before the function is defined.
(Running Python 3.9.0)

This writes "A" to test.txt:

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write("A")
f.close
```

This writes "" to test.txt:

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write("A")
f.close

def func():
    return 1
```

What am I doing wrong/how can I work around it?

Comment: You need to call `f.close` by adding parenthesis: `f.close()`.  It is not flushing the write buffer.  It is just happenstance that it worked in the first case.

Comment: Note that it's good practice to use a `with` statement to open a file in Python, see the [example in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). The `close()` call will then be done automatically and correctly when leaving the indented block below `with`.